what is syntax error in this python code?
    def multiplication_or_sum(num1, num2):
        # calculate product of two number
        product = num1 * num2
        # check if product is less then 1000
        if product <= 1000:
            return product
        else:
            # product is greater than 1000 calculate sum
            return num1 + num2

    # first condition
    result = multiplication_or_sum(20, 30)
    print("The result is", result)


I run this code. and i got syntax error constantly. I don't know what's wrong with this code.

Check the indentation of the if block.  Voting to close as a typo.

Also, for future questions (including this one, if you want to re-open it), include the actual error message. The code runs fine for me, so it is impossible to answer this question without the error message. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Thank you for answering.
This is the exact error message:SyntaxError: invalid syntax
I think there is something wrong with the line "result = multiplication_or_sum(20, 30)" because it turned to red color.

Information like that should go into an [edit], not the comments. Also make sure to include the full traceback and post console output/errors as code-formatted text.

I don't get any error with the example code. Are you sure your code is exactly as showed here (check indentation, and also that you are using spaces instead of tabs). And of course, include the full error traceback.
